# How do I create a DIV that only occupies as much width as its child elements (without specifying a fixed pixel width)?

Tags: html, css, width, element

I would like to have a DIV around my elements that only occupies as much horizontal width as the maximum horizontal width of its elements.  I have these HTML elements …

```
<div id="container-content">
    <h3>My Subscriptions</h3> 
    <table id="subscriptions-table">
        . . .
    </table>
</div>
```

and this style

```
#container-content {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
}

#subscriptions-table {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

but disappointingly, the DIV with class = “container-content” occupies 100% of the width of the screen ( https://jsfiddle.net/ya8b11qf/ ) and I would prefer it only take up as much width as the table within it.  I do not want to specify a fixed pixel width for “container-content”.

Comment: display inline?

Comment: Will that ruin the centering of the content?

Comment: Try it. It's free. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished by applying `display: inline-block;` to the container, like so:

```
#container-content {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And your updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ya8b11qf/1/

To center `#container-content`, just add `text-align: center;` to its parent. Because the content is now displaying `inline`, it responds to text-centering, whereas a standard div (which is `block` display by default) requires the use of `margin: 0 auto;`.

Comment: Thanks but the content is no longer centered.  Any way to address that?

Comment: @Natalia, just add `text-align: center;` to `#main-content`

Comment: @Natalia Garconis is correct. Because the container is now an `inline` element, it will respond to text-centering. You can put `text-align: center;` on the parent of any `inline` element (like text, images, or elements that have `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`) to center them.